# Angular2 RC5 subdomain routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to have separation for auth, public and private sections. The most obvious option would be to just create folders under App. However, I want to point different subdomains at different sections (example.com -> public, auth.example.com -> auth). I have not been able to find info on Angular2 subdomain routing - any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Did u get a solution to this? I'm curious to see how that can be worked out.

Comment: No, I decided to work around this, falling back to folders until I can find a better way